Why does camera shake when parented to animated circle curve?
I'm trying to animate a camera orbiting a sphere. Everything works great except the camera appears to shake when moving around the sphere and I can't figure out why.
The camera is parented to an animated Bezier circle in order to make the camera orbit an unanimated sphere. When the animation is run from the camera view, the sphere appears to bounce a little. I think it’s the camera that’s shaking, but why?
Any suggestions? File attached. Thanks! Blender 4.1.1, Windows 11


Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

I didn't open the file. I'm just guessing. Ive faced this in the past. Have you tried upping the resolution of the path the camera is following?
Properties Editor > Object Data > Shape > Resolution Preview. Try something like 64. I think you can adjust it down in the Active Spline panel too.
